# Ubuntu Terminal on Windows 10: how to fix "kubectl: command not found"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, kubernetes

I installed "Ubuntu Terminal on Windows 10" and tried to execute kubectl commands.

The problem is that I must add the .exe file extension to the command in order to operate it.

If I don't I get:

```
 kubectl: command not found
```

For example:

```
tal@shell130:~$ kubectl.exe version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.0", GitCommit:"cb303e613a121a29364f75cc67d3d580833a7479", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-04-08T16:31:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"wind
ows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.7", GitCommit:"65ecaf0671341311ce6aea0edab46ee69f65d59e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-01-24T19:22:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linu
x/amd64"}
WARNING: version difference between client (1.21) and server (1.11) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1

tal@shell130:~$ kubectl version
kubectl: command not found
```

On the other hand, on powershell, it works for me also without the file extension.

How can I fix this situation?

Thanks

Comment: can you edit your question and paste the command and its output together

Comment: Updated question with an example. Thanks

Comment: I guess you have to install kubectl separately for the Ubuntu environment https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/

Comment: yes that worked! Thanks